# AS3 performance gap between split and splice(0, 1)?

Tags: performance, actionscript

I made the mergeSort algorithm in as3. For removing the first element in an array i used Array.splice(0, 1). Then i remembered Array.split(). I compared the two. 

It turns out that split() is much faster than splice(0, 1).


30k tests on an array with 10 elements

 splice(0, 1): average of 5567 ms

 split: average of 1956 ms, 2.8x faster

With smaller arrays, the performance gap is also smaller. 
30k tests on array with 2 elements
splice(0, 1): average 330 ms

split(): average 206 ms, 1.6x faster

Could someone explain this to me? Does this have something to do with indexing?

Thanks.

code:

```
public static function sort(a:Array):Array{
    if(a.length == 1){
        return a;
    }

    var b = a.splice(a.length / 2, a.length);
    a = sort(a);
    b = sort(b)
    var r = new Array;

    while(a.length && b.length){
        if(a[0] < b[0]){
            r.push(a.shift());
        }else{
            r.push(b.shift());
        }
    }

    while(a.length)
        r.push(a.shift());

    while(b.length)
        r.push(b.shift());

    return r            
}
```

Comment: There is no `split` method, did you mean `slice` instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming Carlo Cannas is right and you compared splice and slice (not split), the result you got is to be expected, as splice modifies an existing Array, which is generally more expensive than creating two new ones, as slice does.

Comment: Sorry that it took so very long to accept this answer. At that time, I wasn't aware of the workings of stackoverflow.